# How to get a 01 string through input()?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to get a string which merely consists of 0 and 1. 
Since raw_input() was renamed to input() in Python 3, I wrote:

```
buf = str(input())
print(buf)
```

However,when I tried '00101',  `buf` surprisingly turned out to be '65'.
Why this happened and how to prevent this?
As a beginner in Python, it confuses me so much.

---

update: Problem solved. See my answer below.

Comment: `input` returns a string in python3 directly. You don't need to call `str` again

Comment: Then you are running python 2 and not python 3.  Check your PATH.  What do you get with `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: Always run `python` from your command line and check the version output :) also `buf = input()` gives you a string as mentioned above.

Comment: do not put the *answer* ("wrong python version") into your *question*, post it as your own *answer* instead. [It is explicitly encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i try this statement in python3 and output was `00101`

btw: output from function `input()` is string, you dont need call `str()` on `input()`

but if you run `input()` in python (python 2.7) you get output `65`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I found that I forgot to remove Python 2.7 directory from environment variables. Furthermore, a number begins with zero is considered as an octal one. That's why I got '65' for '00101' in Python 2. Thank you all.